# Is it possible to get line no while extracting text from pdf doc?

Tags: python, java, itext, pdfbox

Is there an any way to get the text line by line from pdf document or get line no using any library and language.
I'm able to get text from pdf document page by page using these 3 lib pdfbox, itext, aspose-pdf in java.

Comment: PDF format has different interpretation of text present in it. Nevertheless, would you kindly create a post in (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) which is the right place for such discussions related to Aspose.PDF. We will investigate the feasibility of your requirements and share our feedback with you there. This is Asad and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

Using PyMuPDF, this is the simplest way:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    i = 0
    blocks = page.get_text("blocks", sort=True)  # text organized in paragraphs
    for block in blocks:
        for line in block[4].splitlines():
            print(f"Page {page.number}, line {i}: '{line}'")
            i += 1
```

> Every block is a tuple of 4 boundary box coordinates, followed by the string comprising the text of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

PDF has no concept of Line Numbers, since laser text could be any angle.

So which line is 1 is simply a human perception, that for the majority, 1 is the topmost line on a page. However for a PDF that can the the tenth one it writes or the last one since the cartesian system it uses is page bottom to top.

Anyway to nominate numbers for this PDF page

```
pdftotext -layout -f 1 -l 1 -enc UTF-8 "C:\Downloads\SO 76437736 LineNumbers.pdf" - |find /v /n "never2Bfound"

[1]Is it possible to get line no while extracting text from pdf doc?
[2]
[3]Asked today Modified today Viewed 42 times
[4]
[5]           Is there an any way to get the text line by line from pdf document or get line no using any
[6]           library and language. I'm able to get text from pdf document page by page using these 3 lib
[7]
[8]  2 pdfbox, itext, aspose-pdf in java.
[9]
[10]                python java itext pdfbox
[11]
[12]   Share Edit Follow Close Flag                              asked 20 hours ago
[13]                                                                      Seriously
[14]                                                                       135 5
[15]
[16]          the simples pdftotext output is pdftotext -layout which will usually give you lines one by one. now
[17]          the problem with your question is what do you mean ? since you say your able to already get text. PDF
[18]          does not use Line numbers, they are a human requirement only for input to a PDF. see
[19]          stackoverflow.com/a/72778117/10802527 ÔÇô K J 6 hours ago
[20]
[21]1 Answer                                                     Sorted by:
[22]                                                             Reset to default
[23]
[24]                                                               Date created (oldest first)
[25]
[26]   Using PyMuPDF, this is the simplest way:
[27]
[28]1         import fitz # PyMuPDF
[29]
[30]          doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
[31]
[32]          for page in doc:
[33]                i = 0
[34]                blocks = page.get_text("blocks", sort=True) # text organized in paragraphs
[35]                for block in blocks:
[36]                       for line in block[4].splitlines():
[37]                             print(f"Page {page.number}, line {i}: '{line}'")
[38]                             i += 1
[39]
[40]          Every block is a tuple of 4 boundary box coordinates, followed by the string
[41]          comprising the text of the paragraph.
[42]
[43]   Share Edit Follow Flag               edited 16 hours ago  answered 19 hours ago
[44]                                                                      Jorj McKie
[45]                                                                       1,897 1 13 16
[46]♀
```

to save as a file just add a redirector `>SO-Q76437736-Page1.txt`